# String operation in from() method in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we do string operation in `from()` method in MYSQL like:-

```
from(concat(`tab`,`le`))
```

Comment: Perhaps you want dynamic SQL.

Comment: Can't be done like that. Process the string before executing it.

Comment: I am injecting SQL in a web app where inforamtion_schema as a string is not allowed in the $_REQUEST so i need to break information_schema or encode it

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Try this:

```
SET @mytbl=concat('tab','le');
SET @stmt=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @mytbl);
PREPARE statmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE statmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statmt;
```